# Why do I keep having to reboot my AWS ec2 instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, pm2

I have a nodejs app that I'm running on a ubuntu server on an ec2 instance. The code for the app is just this...

```
app.listen(port, () => {
    HorseRacingAPI()
    FootballAPI()
    AmericanFootballAPI()

    setInterval(() => {
        HorseRacingAPI()
    }, 1000 * 120)

    setInterval(() => {
        FootballAPI()
    }, 1000 * 120)

    setInterval(() => {
        AmericanFootballAPI()
    }, 1000 * 120)
})
```

Each of the 3 functions makes a request to an API, reorganises the returned data, and then sends the data to mongodb.

When I run this on my computer, it works great, sometimes a function may fail like 1% of the time, but it runs again 2 minutes later and works. However, when I run this on the ec2 instance, after a couple hours, the ec2 instance fails and won't run the nodejs app again until I reboot the instance and restart the pm2 server.

The pm2 logs look like this...

```
0|server   |     at Timeout.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/TPL-SCRAPI/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:197:23)
0|server   |     at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
0|server   |     at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)
0|server   | MongooseError: Operation `oddsmatchers.updateMany()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
0|server   |     at Timeout.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/TPL-SCRAPI/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:197:23)
0|server   |     at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
0|server   |     at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)
0|server   | MongooseError: Operation `oddsmatchers.updateMany()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
0|server   |     at Timeout.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/TPL-SCRAPI/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:197:23)
0|server   |     at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
0|server   |     at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)
0|server   | MongooseError: Operation `oddsmatchers.updateMany()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
0|server   |     at Timeout.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/TPL-SCRAPI/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:197:23)
0|server   |     at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
0|server   |     at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? I need this code to run forever basically, so what do I need to do to make this happen with essentially 100% reliability?